# Generating single sided buffers on the same side of lines

Tags: pyqgis, buffer

I have a line and a point layers and trying to find points 100m to the left of each line.

The image below shows the single-sided buffer result. As can clearly be seen, one of the buffers is generated on the right side. But of course, it is the left side of the line direction.

[image]

How can I make sure the buffers are generated on the same side?

Here is the script I want to improve:

```
point_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("POINTS")[0]
line_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("LINES")[0]

i = 1
interval = 100 # meter

# Find all points to the left of each lines
for l in line_lyr.getFeatures():
    buffer = l.geometry().singleSidedBuffer(interval, 1, Qgis.BufferSide.Left)
    
    # find the points in the buffer
   
    # assign the lane number (i)   

    i += 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the fact that all lines are parallel and calculate the angle of the lines. Define a main angle (e.g. from the first line), and if a line does not fit that main angle draw the buffer on the otherside.

```py
lines = iface.activeLayer()
interval = 250
for i,line in enumerate(lines.getFeatures()):
    if i == 0:
        myangle = line.geometry().angleAtVertex(0)
    if line.geometry().angleAtVertex(0) == myangle:
        buffer = line.geometry().singleSidedBuffer(interval, 1, Qgis.BufferSide.Left)
    else: 
        buffer = line.geometry().singleSidedBuffer(interval, 1, Qgis.BufferSide.Right)
```

You could add a tolerance if they are not perfectly parallel. E.g. by using `math.isclose()` with a relative or absolute tolerance:

```py
import math
lines = iface.activeLayer()
interval = 250
tolerance = 11 # absolute, degrees for easier use
# you can also use a relative tolerance, e.g. math.isclose(a,b,rel_tol = tolerance)
for i,line in enumerate(lines.getFeatures()):
    if i == 0:
        myangle = math.degrees(line.geometry().angleAtVertex(0))
    if math.isclose(math.degrees(line.geometry().angleAtVertex(0)), myangle, abs_tol = tolerance):
        buffer = line.geometry().singleSidedBuffer(interval, 1, Qgis.BufferSide.Left)
    else: 
        buffer = line.geometry().singleSidedBuffer(interval, 1, Qgis.BufferSide.Right)
```

---

Or do some more fancy stuff like:

```py
import math
import random
lines = iface.activeLayer()
buffers = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs={}'.format(lines.crs().authid()), 'Buffers' , "memory")
buffers.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("sourcefeatid", QVariant.Int), QgsField("lineangle", QVariant.Double), QgsField("mainaingle", QVariant.Double), QgsField("parallel", QVariant.String), QgsField("bufferside", QVariant.String)])
buffersize = 250 # in CRS units
tolerance = 22.5 # absolute; degrees for easier use; you can also use a relative tolerance, e.g. math.isclose(a,b,rel_tol = tolerance)
mainangle = None # define your mainangle here
bufferdirection = None # define a main-direction
# or do some fancy stuff to determine the bufferside
if not bufferdirection or bufferdirection not in ['west','east']:
    bufferdirection = random.choice(['west','east'])

for i,line in enumerate(lines.getFeatures()):
    polyline = line.geometry().asPolyline()
    startpoint, endpoint = QgsPoint(polyline[0]), QgsPoint(polyline[-1])
    
    if i == 0:
        if mainangle is None:
            mainangle = math.degrees(QgsGeometryUtils.lineAngle(startpoint.x(), startpoint.y(), endpoint.x(), endpoint.y()))
        reversemainangle = (mainangle+180)%360
        
    lineangle = math.degrees(QgsGeometryUtils.lineAngle(startpoint.x(), startpoint.y(), endpoint.x(), endpoint.y()))
    print(lineangle)
    
    if bufferdirection == 'west':
        if 0 < lineangle <= 180:
            print('Buffer left')
            bufferside = Qgis.BufferSide.Left
        else:
            print('Buffer right')
            bufferside = Qgis.BufferSide.Right
    elif bufferdirection == 'east':
        if 0 < lineangle <= 180:
            print('Buffer right')
            bufferside = Qgis.BufferSide.Right
        else:
            print('Buffer left')
            bufferside = Qgis.BufferSide.Left
    
    drawbuffer = True
    if math.isclose(mainangle,lineangle,abs_tol=tolerance):
        parallelattr = 'parallel'
        print(parallelattr)
        buffer = line.geometry().singleSidedBuffer(buffersize, 1, bufferside)
    elif math.isclose(reversemainangle,lineangle,abs_tol=tolerance):
        parallelattr = 'reverse parallel'
        print(parallelattr)
        buffer = line.geometry().singleSidedBuffer(buffersize, 1, bufferside)
    else:
        parallelattr = 'not parallel'
        print(parallelattr)
        buffer = line.geometry().singleSidedBuffer(buffersize, 1, bufferside)
        drawbuffer = False
    
    if drawbuffer:
        with edit(buffers):
            newbuffer = QgsFeature()
            newbuffer.setAttributes([line.id(),lineangle,mainangle,parallelattr,str(bufferside)])
            newbuffer.setGeometry(buffer)
            buffers.dataProvider().addFeature(newbuffer)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(buffers)
```

Comment: Not perfectly parallel. It worked after changing `if int(line.geometry().angleAtVertex(0)) == int(myangle):`